# Can I setup a NestJS server on raspbian

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, nestjs, raspbian

I could find many links about raspbian supporting Node.JS but nothing about NestJS directly.

While I know NestJS uses Node.JS, I want to know if raspbian fully supports NestJS.
Or maybe my understanding of these 2 is wrong and my question isn't even relevant.

I intend using Angular, NestJS, TypeORM and PostgreSQL as a fullstack and a Raspberry Pi 3B as hardware. This will be a private web app to develop, practice and keep my tools and a bit of data and medias at hand's reach.

This web and server world is a maze to figure out. Help me out.

Any advice, approach, alternative are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest.js is just a frameworkk which uses TypeScript. The only thing you need to to is just compile your project to JS and run it with Node.
You can establish pipeline like that -> nest build -> node dist/main.js and it will just workk.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Good enough for me.

Comment: @David how did it go? My only attempt failing with npm getting stuck installing packages. Building on my computer and deploying to the rpi did work though. However, I need to use the gpio libraries which I can't run on my computer, so I'm kind of giving up.